# Checking if an array is empty using a while loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have read several of these posts on the site, but still can't find the answer to my problems. I have a while loop where for every entry in the database the table populates. Although if the table in the database is empty, I want it to display a messaged instead. Any ideas of what is wrong here? (aware of the deprecated tags)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))                    
{           
   if(count($row) === 0)
   {
      echo 'No Data';
   }

   <table code>

}
```

Comment: However, `mysql_*` functions are officially **deprecated**. I recommend you to use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: The problem is that the `if` is inside the `while` so it will never be  reached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mysql_num_rows` for counting rows from DB.

```
<?php

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '<table>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<tr>...</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
} else {
    echo 'No result found';
}

?>
```

**EDIT**: updated code for table.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) === 0) {
    echo 'No Data';
} else {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {           
        // code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `mysql_num_rows()` to get count of query result rows

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($rows > 0) {
  // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_num_rows` for counting number of rows are returned in query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) will check the records in database. On true condition it will allow to execute the while loop other wise else condition will execute.

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog");

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo 'No Result Found';
    } else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {           
            // Here your Data
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display when no record found then

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

  {           
  if(count($row) == 0 || count($row) < 1)
   {
    echo 'No Data';
   }
  else
     {
  //print records

      }
  }
```